# Telerik grid Column Aggregate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, grid, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I'm using Telerik Grid(Razor) with MVC. Below are the configuration of the project.

**MVC - 4.0.0.0**

**Telerik.Web.Mvc (.dll) - 2012.1.214.340**

```
 .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Bound(x =>x.Id).Width(100).Aggregate(aggregates => aggregates.Count())  
                     .FooterTemplate(@<text>Total Count: @item.Count</text>)           
                     .GroupFooterTemplate(@<text>Count: @item.Count</text>); 
                        columns.Bound(x => x.Name).Width(50);
                        columns.Bound(x => x.Price).Width(100);
                        columns.Bound(x => x.Qty).Aggregate(agg => agg.Count())
                        .FooterTemplate(@<text> Total Qty: <span>@item.Count</span> </text>);
```

In above block of code I have added **FooterTemplate** for showing Count, but it is showing just label text. Please check below image.

[image: valid XHTML].